# Passing hibernate session object between pages without a db commit

Tags: hibernate

I have a wizard section in my site and I'm trying to pass my hibernate object from one page to the next without a db commit. I'm wondering what the correct approach to doing this without getting lazy loading exceptions etc.

Should I do something like

```
session.save on page 1
session.get on page 2?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

treat your pojo as disconnected from the hibernate session. initialize all properties you will access during your workflow (for example by calling the getters on your pojo). after the workflow is completed, merge the pojo with a fresh hibernate session.

another way to do this, is having another type of (unmapped) bean representing the state of your workflow (dto pattern). this gives you more control and flexibility in modeling the ui part of your wizard, but has the cost of more complexity.

in this scenario you would load the pojo(s) which you need to initialize the page-state-bean in step1, and populate it from them. after completion you load the needed pojos from a fresh session and update them with the userinput pulled from the page-state-bean.

it should look something like this:

```
page1:
  domainObject=session.load()
  pageModel.loadStateFrom(domainObject)
page2:
  domainObject=session.load()
  pageModel.pushStateInto(domainObject)
  session.merge(domainObject)
```

Comment: I'm guessing my object isn't actually in the hibernate session in the beginning of my wizard do to the fact there has been no pk established. Would it be best to just pass the object along through the user session and then save it on the following page? or save before passing the object along to the second page and somehow pull it from the hibernate first level cache and not pass it along through the user session. "Not sure if that's even possible"

Comment: >>Would it be best to just pass the object along through the user session and then save it on the following page?  

propably. if your workflow deals with a new object, it makes little sense to introduce it to hibernate before it is clear that you want to keep it persistent. if you save it prematurely you not only have to deal with hibernates  complexity during the whole workflow. on top of that you'd have to make sure that you remove it from hibernate should the user (or an error) cancel the workflow.
just pass an ordinary pojo along in your user session, and persist it on the last page.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I was getting lazy loading exceptions when just passing a pojo, but I figured out how to force an eager fetch fixing the entire issue. Like you said, I'm just going to pass the pojo.